# overloaded < operator gives "no matching function for call" error when used in another class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I implemented a custom TimeStruct class, where I declare < operator as follows

```
bool operator<(const TimeStruct t2) const;
```

implementation is as follows.

```
bool TimeStruct::operator<(const TimeStruct t2) const
{
//do something, I don't include the actual implementation
return true;
}
```

Then I have another class X where this TimeStruct class is a member, let's call this member field Y. And I am using a vector, and I want to sort this vector on Y field of Class X. Therefore I will need to specify a method which might serve as a basis for the vector's sort method.

Therefore I declared an additional method in X to compare different X's.

```
bool compareX(const X& x1, const X& x2) const;
```

and the implementation is as follows:

```
bool X::compareX(const X& x1, const X& x2) const
{
return (x1.Y.operator<(x2.Y));
}
```

Unfortunately this code does not compile. I am receiving the following error.

```
No matching function call for TimeStruct::operator<(const TimeStruct&) const
candidates are : bool TimeStruct::operator<(TimeStruct&) const
```

I've been scratching my hair for the last hour, can anybody point out what I've been doing wrong.

Comment: Why do people keep changing the code that fails when asking? The compiler is seeing the signature as taking a non-const reference, but the question code takes a const value. -1

Comment: Not everybody has the same security setup on their machines, Let me give you an example, maybe you can understand a little better, My code is on an intranet machine with no internet connectivity because of security concerns, with no usb access etc, believe me if I have the option copy and paste my code, I would do that, but unfortunately I have to retype the damn thing on another computer.  right after posting my question,I realized that my code is slightly different than original code that was giving error therefore I edited it,I don't think that anybody has to ask your permission...

Comment: There is no need to ask for permission and less so from me, but the question as it is **now** and the compiler error are **different**. The code in the question would not cause the compiler error that you are showing (as a matter of fact it would compile). I am not saying that you need to copy the file, but you need to avoid removing the problem from the code!

Comment: As you might accept, typing the code one more time is an error prone process, my intention was not altering the code, I had a typo, with that being said, your attitude is not constructive at all, people make mistakes every day even if they don't intend to, I suggest you to get over it, you will live longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass by *const reference* in your `TimeStruct` operator:

```
bool operator<(const TimeStruct& t2) const;
```

and, according to the error message, you have provided

```
bool operator<(TimeStruct&) const
```

Comment: thanks a lot, can't believe that I have missed something trivial like that.

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be a const **reference** specifier in the operator declaration.

Furthermore, you may want to turn `operator<` from a member function into a friend function.
It's usually best practice.